# spreedsheet script time limit

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to import to a spreedsheet mails addreses, messages and sending time of all messages with a specific label, I have more than 1300 messages on that label.

So far i was doing them by a 100 messages each run, because thats what I saw the limit was,
but now, after importing 500 rows, my script stoped working and gave me an

> "TypeError: Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined. (Línea
>   19)Ignorar"

what should I do? wait two hours? wait a day? start a new spreedsheet?

Thanks,
leo

Answer (score 0):

the quota for Gmail read is 10000 / day (see [quotas on the dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard)) . Are you sure the error doesn't come from elsewhere ? Maybe you could provide some code you use ?

Following your comments (thanks for the code info) I would suggest to speed up your code by avoiding these numerous setValue() that takes a lot of time... try this instead : (replace the relevant part in your code)

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var toShow=new Array()
    for (var i = 502; i < 550; i++) { 
    var myThread = GmailApp.search("is:w-destino-mensajes")[i]; 
   if(myThread.length>0){
    var message = myThread.getMessages()[0]; 
    toShow.push([message.getDate(),message.getFrom(),message.getBody()]); 
}
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow,2,toShow.length,toShow[0].length).setValues(toShow)
```

EDIT : I don't think your issue is about limits, seeing the error message I guess myThread returns an empty value in some case and that creates an error. You could try to add an existence condition before trying to getMessages (see code above).

Comment: the script was working fine, I was only changing the iteration index number each time I excecuted.

Comment: <code>

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  
  
  //for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  for (var i = 502; i < 550; i++) {
    
   var myThread = GmailApp.search("in:w-destino-mensajes")[i];
   var message = myThread.getMessages()[0];
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 2).setValue(message.getDate());
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(message.getFrom());
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(message.getBody());
     
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}
</code>

Comment: I still have the same error, I may have reached a limit on the spreadsheet, would have to test your script tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your tip.

As soon as I have the script working, I may write a gtug blog post with a tutorial for this.
So its important to know where the limit was.

If I passed the gmail 10k read limit, does my gmail account get blocked?

Comment: That gave me an error too.
It may be because I exceeded the gmail read quota and returns an ampty object.

I will try again tomorro and let you know, 

I really apretiate your effort!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you check this var myThread = GmailApp.search("in:w-destino-mensajes")[i];  I believe it's a typo, should be 'is' in place of 'in'

Comment: The script was working fine until it reached 500 rows in the spreadsheet.
I tried your suggestion, with the same error

Comment: I would exclude quota thresholds being reached as the cause of your empty object. From experience, when you hit a quota limit you will get a very descriptive exception thrown.

Comment: Confirmed, the problem was that I reached some limit, and the therad returned an empty object!